# Conditionally use a varied number of items in each iteration

Tags: c#, iterator, iteration

I guess this is really simple and just involes the use of a iterator and .MoveNext() method.

But let's say you are iterating through a collection, you do some work on the collection but based on some condition in each "loop" you might have to grab 2 or more items and basically skip over them so you don't loop through them next.

Example:

```
foreach (Fish fish in ParcelOfFish)
{
    GiverPersonFish(fish);
}
```

Here I'm just iterating through a collection of Fish and passing them to a method. Some fishes are small so I have to give the person another one so it won't starve.

```
foreach (Fish fish in ParcelOfFish)
{
    GiverPersonFish(fish);

    if (fish.IsSmall)
    {
        GiverPersonFish(ParcelOfFish.MoveNext()); // here I want to give him the next fish
    }
}
```

How will this work so that the second fish I give will not iterate in next loop?

Also to make this trickier, it's unfair that a person might get a big and a small fish so whenever there is a small fish I wan't to grab another small fish from the iteration and then go on.

So if the order was

```
Small
Big
Big
Small
Big
Small
```

after first "loop" he will get two small (index 0 and 3) and it will iterate through the rest like this:

```
Big
Big
Big
Small
```

The compiler doesn't seem to like when a iteration is modified like that while iterating through it.

Comment: As is, it seems that you give all the fishes to the same person, so what is the deal with advanced more than one fish each iteration?

Comment: foreach doesn't fit here. Maybe using a queue is better.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri Well we don't really know what happens in the GivePersonFish() method and it's not really important.

Comment: @IngóVals in such a case, it does not even matter what fish you pass to each call to GivePersonFish. You are concerned about people starvation while "People" is private to the scope of GivePersonFish. Then you must distribute fishes within the scope of GivePersonFish and don't care about the foreach loop.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri So you are saying that the person will only eat for one day,  I Should rather TeachPersonToFish() and he will eat for a lifetime?

Comment: @IngóVals No, I don't have an opinion on moral principles, I just base my opinion on Object-Oriented design criteria. If some information is not relevant in the scope of the for-each loop, then it does not care for the sake of the loop iteration. You showed concern on how fishes are distributed among people so BOTH fishes and people are relevant or both are not relevant for the iteration. If you need to make an optimal distribution of fishes, try a different approach as for example, the Sum-Bottleneck algorithm or any other partitioning algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is solvable through the `Enumerator`

```
using (var enumerator = ParcelOfFish.GetEnumerator())
{
    // Bla bla whatever you need, but remember the first call to .MoveNext();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            break;

    // Your actions here. MoveNext() is bool and proceeds to the new item.
    // Try using while (!condition) { } here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterations, by design, aren't meant to work like this. If you need more flexible behavior you should use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a foreach loop (`foreach(Foo foo in bar)`), use a plain old for loop (`for(int i = 0; i < bar.Length; i++)`).

This will let you do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParcelOfFish.Length; i++)
{
    Fish fish = ParcelOfFish[i];
    GiverPersonFish(fish);

    if (fish.IsSmall && i+1 < ParcelOfFish.Length)
    {
        GiverPersonFish(ParcelOfFish[++i]); // give him the next fish
    }
}
```

Using a for loop will also let you look through your list for another small fish, give it to the person, and remove it from the list (this time assuming ParcelOfFish is a list, not an array):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParcelOfFish.Count; i++)
{
    Fish fish = ParcelOfFish[i];
    GiverPersonFish(fish);

    if (fish.IsSmall)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < ParcelOfFish.Count; j++)
        {
            Fish fish2 = ParcelOfFish[j];
            if (fish2.IsSmall)
            {
                GiverPersonFish(fish2); // give him the next small fish
                ParcelOfFish.RemoveAt(j);
                break;                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This also will not give **next small fish**

Comment: I answered the first part of the question, and indicated how to solve the rest of the problem, but I've added an example for the second part too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a queue instead.

```
var queue = new Queue<Fish>(ParcelOfFish);
while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    var fish = queue.Dequeue();

    if (fish.IsSmall && queue.Count > 0) 
    {
        var fish2 = queue.Dequeue();

        if (fish2.IsSmall)
            GiverPersonFish(fish); // give them the first small fish
        else
            queue.Enqueue(fish); // throw it back to the end of the queue

        GiverPersonFish(fish2);
    }
    else
        GiverPersonFish(fish);
}
```

Also works with a stack.

Comment: `queue.Count > 0` is better than `queue.Any()` since that is an extension which enumerates the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Enumerator<Fish> enumerator = ParcelOfFish.GetEnumerator();
Queue<Fish> bigFishCache = new Queue<Fish>(){ };
Boolean smallFishSwitch = false;

while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if(smallFishSwitch)
    {
        if(enumerator.Current == BigFish)
        {
             bigFishCache.Enqueue(enumerator.Current);
        }
        else
        {
             smallFishSwitch = false;
             GivePersonFish(enumerator.Current);
             ForEach(Fish fish in bigFishCache)
             {
                  GivePersonFish(fish);
             }
             bigFishCache.Clear();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        smallFishSwitch = enumerator.Current == SmallFish;
        GivePersonFish(enumerator.Current);
    }    
}
```